# Is asking allowed for sensitive subjects?

Tags: discussion

How we  answer for debatable questions?
eg.

avoid and dont answer it ,because i have no solution ,just cause injury to the situation
and dont insist my opinion on debatable issues
or
use terms thats win-win outcome to both .

what else can we do.

we need to discuss that to make this site members more cooperative .

Answer (score 4):

You have to keep in mind that StackExchange sites are not forums that are intended for discussion or debates. They are specifically designed to be a place to go and ask questions and get answers. If the issue you are addressing is more of a topic than an actual question, then it will pretty much always be closed.

Comment: so debatable questions will be closed and are not allowed

Comment: It just depends on what the question is and how it is asked. If it can be clearly and objectively answered, no problem. The main point is that SE is NOT here for discussion or debate; it is here for answers!

Comment: But sometimes debating can help people understand why they are wrong, and sometimes it is more effective than explaining.

Comment: @JeffreyLin Sure, but that's not what SE is here for.

Answer (score 4):

If the question relates to History, it is quite reasonable to ask for details on the current debate over the subject.

Where it starts to venture into flamebait territory is when the question asks for a judgement on which side it right, or when posters take some of the answers that way.

Comment: Easier said than done.

Comment: @astabada - Quite.